# How to stop a failed Akeneo job

Tags: bigcommerce, akeneo

I am configuring the Webkul BigCommerce plugin to connect to BigCommerce, but the job has failed.

For some reason, the task is just sitting in the job queue. There's no option to stop it anywhere;
[Example of failed task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AipmX.png)

Does anyone know a way to kill an individual job in Akeneo? I've got the command to clear all jobs, but not 1 specific one.

A way to stop the job